# Spring Security basics

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-security

How to make a link visible only if an authenticated user has correspondent permissions?

I'm using JSF, and as I understand, I should use `rendered` attribute of a component which should call backing bean's boolean method.

I've even found correspondent code some time ago but now I can't find it again. So, can anyone give me an example of such boolean method which *works with spring security*? (or, even better, link to some article which describes this issue).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the [SecurityContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/context/SecurityContextHolder.html) to access the currently logged in user. We then use the users getAuthorities() method to get her roles, resulting in (roughly) the following:

```
((UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getPrincipal()).getAuthorities();
```

Comment: .. and to solve the particular problem, wrap it in a getter and make use of it in a boolean expression.

Answer (score 4):

The `rendered` attribute (and `disabled` and `readonly`) does not necessarily expect a getter method which returns `boolean` like this:

```
public boolean getBooleanValue() {
    return this.booleanValue;
}
```

Those attributes just expect a boolean **expression**, which can be any of the following examples:

```
<h:someComponent rendered="#{myBean.booleanValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{myBean.intValue > 10}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{myBean.objectValue == null}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{myBean.stringValue != 'someValue'}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!empty myBean.collectionValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!myBean.booleanValue && myBean.intValue != 0}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{myBean.stringValue == 'oneValue' || myBean.stringValue == 'anotherValue'}" />
```

The `is` prefix is by the way also allowed for `boolean` getters:

```
public boolean isBooleanValue() {
    return this.booleanValue;
}
```

You can wrap whatever API the Spring Security is using in the getter and make use of it in a boolean EL expression in one of the aforementioned ways.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the acegi-jsf components : http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2006/01/19/acegi%5Fjsf%5Fcomponents%5Fhit%5Fthe/

basically you should access the principal check its authority ...

Comment: This article is over 3 years old and in the meanwhile Acegi was taken over by Spring under the name .. yes, Spring Security.